# What's the significance of negative indices in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indices

I was wondering why negative indices in python are so important - are there any applications? I could just use

```py
my_list[len(my_list) - 1]
```

to find the last element of my_list. Why do we need

```py
my_list[-1]
```

To find the last element?

EDIT:
It's not that I don't understand what `my_list[-1]` means, I want to know where this might be used.

Comment: Because it's simpler, and simple is important. To get the element at index `n`, you could also write `my_list[len(my_list) - (len(my_list) - n)]`. But we don't do that because it's more complex than `my_list[n]`.

Comment: Where would it be used? Also I get it is simpler, but I imagine it is hard to live with if somebody decides to learn python...

Comment: This is a different question than what you posed originally. You wrote: "I could just use `my_list[len(my_list) - 1]` to find the last element of my_list. Why do we need `my_list[-1]` To find the last element?" The use cases of `my_list[len(my_list) - 1]` are the same as `my_list[-1]`, it's just that the latter is simpler than the former.

Comment: That part was an example.